# Не отображается форма ввода

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Начала работать с формами, но они решили не работать со мной. 
Если перейти по адресу polls/create, то появляется только кнопка сохранения, а CharField - нет. Если нажать на кнопку, то появляется ошибка, написанная в конце вопроса
Пробовала через FormView, но CharField все равно не отображается, хоть и без вызова ошибки

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('create/', views.create),
    path('save/', views.save_question),
]
```

**view.py**

```
def create(request):
    return render(request, 'polls/create.html')


def save_question(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            text = request.POST['question text']
            #сохранение изъятых данных 
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/polls/')
    else:
        form = QuestionForm()

    return render(request, 'create.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms


class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    question_text = forms.CharField(label='Question text', max_length=300)
```

**create.html**

```
<form action="/polls/save/" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

**Ошибка:**
Request Method: POST  
Request URL:    127.0.0.1:8000/polls/save/  
Django Version: 3.0.6  
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist  
Exception Value:    create.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Форма не отображается потому что отсутствует в контексте. Необходимо передавать её по аналогии с `save_question`:

```
def create(request):
    form = QuestionForm()
    return render(request, 'polls/create.html', {'form': form})
```

или перенести всю логику из `save_question` в `create`, так будет лучше.